# Browser interact with external application

Tags: windows, cross-browser, activex

I have a webpage that which need to access some user data on his windows PC.

Ex.Read Outlook Email , due to security restrictions browsers wont allow this.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Write an ActiveX control ? [what about FF,Chrome]

I need this work with Firefox,IE,Chrome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this - it would be a huge security/privacy issue if a browser could access information on the user's machine. The only way to get Outlook emails would be to tell the user to export their emails from Outlook and have them upload the exported emails to your website.

Comment: I dont think so ,at least in the case of IE,I think that i can use an activex control to interact with OS,so there should be a client APP running on CLIENT machine to interact with browser , for IE i can choose activex control ,but it will not work with FF or others.

Comment: OK that's fine. I don't know anything about ActiveX, so I can't help you with that. Thanks.

Comment: I am not arguing that i am perfect , thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a tool like [Google Calendar Sync](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98565) that your users would download and install.

They would have to input their website credentials or a token that you generate for them and your app would do whatever needs to be done on the local PC.  You may also have a trust issue as well. Will your users trust running your app to read their emails? Depends on the situation I guess, but a totally browser based solution probably won't work if it needs to be cross-browser compliant.

Comment: This is not a public website , so there is no problem with TRUST.I am ready to make a client app,however i dont know how to interact with this APP through FF or other browser except IE.

Comment: You won't need to really.  the App would upload information straight to you website's database.  The website would just read it from there. This takes out the need for desktop interaction from a browser.

Comment: still i need to force the user to open the application on page load,how its posible ? and it will be a performance issue ,first upload the data to ther serve and then fetch from servers,actually what i need to do is fetch outlook emails from users Outlook app and filter it and show on page . [NO IMAP/POP solution posible]

Comment: If this is internal, why use a website? Write a desktop app in the first place.  Is Outlook running exchange? You can just pull their email from exchange instead.  You are either using exchange or POP. Or you can write an Outlook add-on that replicates email to your website. At some point, you have to question the purpose of the whole solution and determine if this is really the best way to go about it.

Comment: Another thought, is use IE Frame for FF and Chrome and then write your ActiveX. Technically all users are using IE but it's transparent within the other browsers.

Comment: Actually the client want to use the RICH features of Outlook , also he need a website to do all these.This is the problem,there are so many requirments like this ,he want to drap nd drop attachments from a web page to outllook.I cannot use any other kind of protocols ..let me think about the IE FRAME.

Comment: Does he want it to make his coffee too? :)